# PyArmor - retrieving license info

Tags: python, obfuscation, pyarmor

As a registered PyArmor user, I can retrieve my license information using `pyarmor register`. The command returns various licensing data including registration code, my name, etc. My question is - does any of this data get included in an obfuscated package? In other words - having obtained an obfuscated code/package, would I be able to trace which license has been used to obfuscate it?